# AS3: How do I break up a function to avoid the 15 second time out rule?

Tags: actionscript-3, timeoutexception

I have a function that works, but if I increase the record number, the fifteen second timeout error occurs. I've seen allusions to "batchifying" a function, breaking it up into chunks, to fool the processor into starting the 15 seconds over again, but can't seem to get it to work.
Code:

```
    startBatch=0;
private function findDupes():void {
    var el:Number;    //elapsed time variable
    timeoutTime = getTimer();
    for (var i:int = startBatch; i < numTix; i++) { // numTix = total number of records
        for (var j:int = i + 1; j < numTix; j++) {
            if (individualTicket[i] == individualTicket[j]) {
                // mark duplicate
            }
        }
        el = getTimer() - timeoutTime;
        if (el > 1000) {
            trace("batched out");
            batchOut(i);
            return;
        }
    }
    weAreDone();
}

private function batchOut(i:int):void {
    updateTB2(i); //attempts to update a textbox and FAILS to do so
    trace("Out at # ", i);
    if (i < numTix) {
        startBatch = i;
        findDupes();
    }
    else {
        weAreDone();
    }
}
```

So, every second, it "batches out" and starts the findDupes() function over at the new number (startBatch). I had hoped that this would reset the timeout error, but instead I get crap on a stick.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: You need to check for the time in the inner loop, then save the value of outer loop to process the remaining part at the next frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rework your `batchOut` function. Currently, it does not allow Flash engine to update anything on screen because it instantly calls for another iteration of `findDupes`, instead it should return and set up class for another iteration once next frame would start. I assume here that there's a `stage` variable available within this code. You need something to allow listening for `Event.ENTER_FRAME` in order to do this kind of batching, `stage` is an universal anchor for a display object.

```
private function batchOut(i:int):void {
    updateTB2(i); //attempts to update a textbox and FAILS to do so
    trace("Out at # ", i);
    if (i < numTix) {
        startBatch = i+1; // your findDupes pass the already processed value of outer index
        // findDupes(); this is a recursion call, drop
        if (!(stage.hasEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,continueBatch)) {
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,continueBatch);
        }
    }
    else {
        weAreDone();
        if (stage.hasEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,continueBatch)) {
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,continueBatch);
        }
    }
}
// now the function to be called
private function continueBatch(e:Event):void {
    // this is called in the NEXT frame, so you can freely call your worker function
    findDupes();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Vesper! My reputation won't show my upvote, but I tried! :) I did accept your answer, though. The major issue I was having, which you solved for me, is that my code was not advancing to the next frame, thereby breaking the 15 second countdown, right?

Comment: Exactly. The code flow needs to be released (`return` from everywhere) in order for Flash to go to next frame.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the "heavy lifting" in a worker or two. Workers are non-blocking and should solve your problem. Here's more about them: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html

Comment: Interesting! I never heard of Workers before. I'll do some reading.